# Visual sync UI in runloop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I notice that many apps try to queue up main thread UI changes to the end of the run loop, performing them in batches.  2 perhaps obvious things I don't understand are: 1) why is this important 2) what are some of the best techniques to achieve this?  The 2 I have seen but only vaguely understand are adding a run loop observer that calls a method that does the UI changes and 2) using a `CADisplayLink` (on iOS) or `CVDisplayLink` (on Mac) and having UI changes happen in "ticks".  I know the equivalent of this in the browser world is batching changes on requestAnimFrame.  Can somebody explain why this is necessary more and perhaps some more detail about the different approaches on the iPhone and Mac to do this?